# What are these SMD ICs marked 2111B and JRC?

Tags: analog

I got them at a garage sale.

I have googled NJM2111B and looked at all of the sites like alldatasheet.com and could not find it. Does anyone know what the pinout and function is or where I can find a datasheet?

Answer (score 1):

With no photo or package description, this is a guess . . .

It could be a high voltage gate driver for a switching power circuit.  Originally made by International Rectifier.

https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IR2111-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c810e51682

https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/gate-driver-ics/ir2111/

Answer (score 0):

The NJM2111 appears to be a chip from the New Japan Radio Company (JRC), but I have not been able to find any information on it (this answer previously referenced a datasheet, but I had typoed the search query and it was for the NJM2211).

The only references I've found so far to its existence are [this product discontinuation notice](https://www.mouser.com/pcn/njr_181220_njr_discon_letter_4inches_termnation.pdf) from 2018, where it's the 34th listed discontinued product, and a handful of search-engine-cached web pages for suppliers of dubious reliability that used to, but no longer, reference the chip as an op amp:

[image: a search result linking to a futureelectronics.com page that the cached copy has the text "NJM2111 Series 2 - 4.5 1 Ghz 2 mV 260 V/μs Single Operational Amlifier[sic] SOT-23-5"]
[image: a search result linking to a findic.kr page with the same text]
[image: a search result linking to an omo-ic.com page with the same text]

Incidentally, most of these type of references are on pages about the NJM2711, which may be evidence that the NJM2711 is a similar chip, perhaps a pin-compatible replacement.

Answer (score 0):

JRC2112 and 2114 are opamps, so it could be an opamp too.

You can check the pinout using a multimeter in diode mode. All the opamp inputs and outputs should be connected to the positive and negative supply pins via ESD protection diodes. Also quite often there's a pair of antiparallel diodes between the input transistors to protect them.